# How to Beat Black Phantoms in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

Quick intro - I love Dark Souls. I think it's amazingly challenging.

The only problem is I get killed so much by invading Phantoms that I hardly play in Human Form enough to enjoy the whole mechanic.

Typically, I've found Phantoms entering my world will occasionally use very advanced magic or have really powerful weapons. Keeping my character < lvl10 does not seem to stop the Phantoms.

Kicking a Black Phantom off a cliff, while an incredibly satisfying way to win a fight, kind of sucks too because you don't get the souls.

So, guys, how do you do it? How do you defend yourself against Black Phantoms?

Comment: Personally I don't play online if I want to enjoy the game in any capacity. The plot based black phantoms will still show up so you do not lose out on any content and real people will not so you can stop hating yourself. This obviously does not answer your actual question but it's nice advice and people seem to forget its possible.

Comment: @Reafexus This is definately true, I guess you might say it depends on how much you enjoy the multiplayer functionality. Personally, I love playing with other players online, so this makes coping with BP a necessity!

Comment: It really depends on you connection speed too as lag is a real problem. on regular occasions I have players starting infront of me and glitching behind me and stabbing me in the back its infuriating when people have slow connection speed...

Comment: I didn't know you lost the souls when you kicked them off the ledge.

Answer (score 8):

There are two "danger" zones when it comes to being invaded:

1. Right around beginning level, from around SL1 to SL10. At this range, you are in danger of being invaded by specially-designed PvP builds, particularly min-maxing Pyromancers. These players take advantage of the relative lack of skill in newcomers and overwhelm them with specially made PvP builds.
2. SL40 is where many other PvP builds will max out. You generally won't have *as much* a problem with these invaders as they tend to hang around end-game areas.

As for surviving invaders, there are several methods. If you can, recruit other players by interacting with their soapstone signs. White signs will summon White Phantoms while golden signs will summon members of the Sunlight Covenant. It really doesn't matter which kind of Phantoms you summon, although members of the Sunlight Covenant (Sunbros) are often considered more skilled and generally have experience with aiding other players.

By summoning allied Phantoms, you have already increased your chances of survival. Black Phantoms can only invade one at time so outnumbering them is a good way to kill them. Don't forget to use Estus Flasks when you have allied Phantoms as they cannot use theirs, but your Estus Flask will recover their health as well.

When you get the message that you are being invaded, don't go searching for the Black Phantom. Often, these invaders are skilled at PvP and will take every advantage they can, commonly lying in wait in areas that easily catch other players off guard. Rather, find a defensible location and wait there. Eventually, the Black Phantom will grow restless and start looking for you, which gives you the advantage.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Usually my first strategy is to call for backup if available - I didn't know Sunbros tend to be better!

Comment: Well, it's more of the fact that helping others as Phantoms is the entire point of the Sunlight Covenant, so members of that covenant tend to have more experience playing with others.

Comment: Sunbros are the yellow signs. The white ones are Way of White.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan White ones are everyone else, not necessarily Way of White.

Comment: @Yuki: Ah yes, you're right.

Comment: It would actually make sense that sunbros are better, since helping other people defeat bosses is a requisite of getting in (requirement: Faith + (5 * number of times you helped another player beat a boss) > 30)